# Apache 2.2 doesn't start after installing PHP 5.6 on Windows 8.1

Tags: php, apache

I'm setting up an development environment on a Windows 8.1 machine.

I successfully installed Apache 2.2, and downloaded php-5.6.3-Win32-VC11-x86.

I added the following lines at the end of httpd.conf

```
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP5"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP5/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I also added

```
application/x-httpd-php .php
```

to the `myme.types` file

If I comment out `PHPIniDir` or `LoadModule` apache will start normally.

Also, all extensions are commented out on the `PHP.ini` file, and the extension directory is set as

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Any help will be hugely appreciated.

EDIT 1:
The only thing in error log is about server shutdow

```
[Sun Nov 23 14:56:07 2014] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Nov 23 14:56:07 2014] [notice] Child 6192: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Sun Nov 23 14:56:08 2014] [notice] Child 6192: Released the start mutex
[Sun Nov 23 14:56:09 2014] [notice] Child 6192: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Nov 23 14:56:09 2014] [notice] Child 6192: Child process is exiting
[Sun Nov 23 14:56:09 2014] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your apache log file for errors! see what the

You mention apache 2.2, yet you are using a dll called php5apache2_4.dll.
This dll is according to the name specifically build for apache 2.4. This is likely to cause issues, the  last php version which has a dll for apache 2.2 for windows on the [php website](http://windows.php.net) is php 5.4.35.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So what do you suggest? Upgrade Apache or downgrade PHP?

Comment: I would recommend upgrading Apache, that way you will be able to use the latest php version and the latest php functions. Unless you specifically want to test with an older php version because you want to make sure your code also runs on the older php version.

Comment: Thanks, everything is working now that I've upgraded to Apache 2.4 (and putted PHPIniDir in the last line).

Comment: And where can I get php 5.6 for apache 2.2?