# Upgrade PHP 5.5.x to 5.6.11 on windows 7

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to upgrade my existing PHP `5.5.x` to `5.6.11` on windows 7 manually. I'm not interested in XAMPP for now. PHP `5.5.x` is currently installed and works fine locally on my machine i.e. `http://localhost`

I grabbed a copy of `php-5.6.11-Win32-VC11-x86` from http://windows.php.net/download/ un-packed the windows binaries and put them where my current ones are e.g. `C:\php`

I use my current `.ini` file for all intents and purposes and copy that across also. It should now be a simple case of restarting the server with 
my upgrade successful - only the server fails to start with 'The requested operation has failed!' and no errors reported in my Apache logs?

Nothing has changed in my `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

What's strange is when I go to the terminal

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.11 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2015 20:55:40)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

So it appears that `5.6.11` IS installed, indeed `$ php -h` reveals a host of information but Apache fails to start with no clues?

How do I complete the upgrade?

Comment: *but Apache fails to start* => take a look in the error log

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091108/apache-2-2-doesnt-start-after-installing-php-5-6-on-windows-8-1 ... PHP 5.6 uses *php5apache2_4.dll* - which is compiled for Apache2.4 and I'm guessing that since you're not using XAMPP you've got a 2.2 install?

Comment: I'm using `php5apache2_4.dll` and Apache is indeed 2.4

Comment: Hmmm well, just for the hell of it, since I'm still running 5.4 on my local machine I'll attempt to patch up to 5.6 and see what happens :)

Comment: @donald123 The error logs report nothing.

Comment: Well - I literally just pulled down the same *php-5.6.11-Win32-VC11-x86* file; moved my current **php** install folder and created an empty **php** folder in it's place - copied the contents of that zip file across and then copied the old **php.ini** from my previous 5.4.7 install into the new 5.6.11 install ... and it worked fine. So it doesn't look as though there are any incompatibility issues between the 5.4 php.ini file and the 5.6 version.

Comment: @CD001 Fair enough, thanks. I wonder what the problem is with mine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83878/discussion-between-cookie-and-cd001).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed the 64 bit version - it now works!